# JavaScript Mocha test debugging in WebStorm

Tags: mocha.js, tdd, webstorm

I've just started using Mocha (+Chai) in WebStorm IDE for my Node.js project.
And I found out that I can't find familiar console pane, where I can type in expressions.
Also I see no easy way to re-run failed unit-test code in plain node.js (without mocha, because I need header with imports and Chai and I need to remove "describe", "it"...), so I can fix the code.

WebStorm is quite popular, Mocha and TDD too, so my question is:

How do you do TDD in WebStorm? How do you solve this problem?

- Maybe I'm missing some button in IDE which opens console
- Or maybe there is a way to simply run this unit-test separately in Node.js
  somehow.
- Or maybe you just live with this as it is and just
  copy-paste code to some 'test.js' manually?

Comment: you can't run mocha tests without mocha, with plain Node.js... I have no idea what you are talking about

Comment: if you just need to quickly evaluate some javascripot code with node.js, create a new scratch file (*File | New | Scratch file, JavaScript*), paste your code there, then using *Run* command in its right-click menu to run it with Node.js